# unable to copy multiple files in cmake (windows)

Tags: cmake

Ive got the following lines on my cmake

```
add_custom_command(TARGET
        myAppSDK POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/client/media/*.*"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/include/client/media"
        DEPENDS myAppSDK 
        )
```

this works in both Linux and MacOS, but in windows it does not work with the error

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x1'
```

It seems like Cmake on windows does not support copying multiple files because if I change the line from (asterisk dot asterisk) to specifying individual files it works. The thing is, if I do it that way it will be a lot of files to specify.

Im using CMAKE version 3.17.5
Compiler: MSVC
in windows.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: [Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-command-line-tool) for `cmake -E copy` clearly states that "Wildcards are not supported.".

Comment: oh ok, but why does it work in Linux or MacOS? 
Any work around to copy multiple files to a directory?

Comment: You may collect required files with `file(GLOB)` command (outside of `add_custom_command`) and then use result of that command (as variable) in the custom command. If you need to collect files inside the custom command, you may use native commands for copy files, like `cp` on Linux or `copy` on Windows, and switch between them depending of current platform. As cross-platform solution, you may write a simple CMake script which does copying and run it with `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P <script>` in your custom command. Inside that script you could use `file(COPY)` command for copy the files.

Comment: Actually, the intention to copy files into **source tree** `(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/include/client/media`) seems unusual. Don't you want to **install** files in that way and choose `dist` as installation directory? For installing files, there is a special `install()` command which installs file into directory specified by `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable.